# How can I disable the MediaWiki login page?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm getting a lot of bot hits on `Special:UserLogin` on several of my MediaWiki wikis. How can I (temporarily) disable `Special:UserLogin`?

The [DisableSpecialPages extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DisableSpecialPages) doesn't want to disable `Special:Userlogin`.

I simply added these lines right after `function load()` in  `SpecialUserLogin.php`:

```
            echo 'Temporarily disabled. Sorry.';
            // Temporarily disabled UserLogin
            exit();
```

But I'm hoping there's a nicer more *MediaWiki* way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Blacklist

Comment: Just hiding the login link *might* keep bots away: [Manual:Preventing_access#Removing_the_Login_link](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Removing_the_Login_link_from_all_pages)

Answer (score 1):

Those bots are trying to register accounts on your wiki. If they don't manage to, then the situation is not that bad. What you requested is easily achieved, just add to your LocalSettings.php:

```
unset( $wgSpecialPages['UserLogin'] );
```

However this is *not* a good idea. If you don't need users to register on their own, install the [ConfirmAccount](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmAccount) extension. In the extremely unlikely case that mere visits to the special page cause serious issues, password-protect it in your webserver (e.g. .htaccess for Apache).